# how to quickly run a script or file with python without having to manually type in terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started learning tkinter for python a while ago. Is there any way to automate the process of manually typing 'python3 myFile.py' every time I make a change on my code. It's kinda tedious when trying to design something, ty.

Comment: Use an IDE, like PyCharm, that can execute your code by pressing a hotkey or clicking a button.

Comment: You can use Jupyter Notebooks

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote all working answers, and accept the one you like the most. Probably you know this, but this is to let the community know which answers were useful and to reward the people for their time and effort as well ;) See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) program to make your coding life much easier. Many let you run scripts just by clicking a button or with a keyborad shortcut as well.

Some examples are [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/learning-center/), and more.

Comment: For a program no longer under developement this seems not overly attractive as solution.

Comment: @guidot The OP says "every time I make a change on my code", that means it's under development, right?

Answer (score 0):

The way to automate the recognition as command is depending on the host operating system you don't mention. See [this page](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/) under the headline "Using the Script Filename".

Answer (score 0):

You can use watchdog library (pip3 install watchdog) to monitor for the file changes in current directory. This does sound like a bad idea to just re-launch a tkinter script every time you save it, but it's definitely possible. I'll demonstrate on a "hello world" tkinter app and the code that keeps killing and re-launching it every time you save that app py file. The monitoring code is as commented as it gets, so read the comments.

**tkinter_app.py**

```
from tkinter import *
print("Hello, Console!")
top = Tk()
Label(top, text="Hello, Tkinter!").pack()
top.mainloop()
```

**monitor.py**

```
# config, note that the file may be updated chunk by chunk, 
# hence the need for a grace period
APP = 'tkinter_app.py'
GRACE_PERIOD = 1.5

# we need the watchdog, observer interface to implement, 
# and a bunnch of the usual imports
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os, sys, subprocess, threading 

# this class will handle the watchdog observer callbacks and restart our app
class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EventHandler, self).__init__()
        self.app = None     # this will store the process object after we start our app
        self.timer = None   # this is going to be our grace period/debounce timer object
        self.restart()      # start the app for the first time

    def restart(self):
        # already running? kill! TODO: impelement a less brutal way to stop it
        if self.app!=None and self.app.poll()==None: 
            self.app.kill()
        # run the app using the same python executable we are using now, 
        # make sure we create a new console for it
        self.app = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, APP], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

    def arm_restart_after_grace_period(self):
        # we need a way to 'debounce' chunked updates, i've decided to use a timer for that
        if self.timer!=None:
            self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = threading.Timer(GRACE_PERIOD, self.restart)
        self.timer.start()

    def on_modified(self, event):
        # any file changes in the monitored directory cause
        # this callback to be fired, possibly multiple times in a row
        if os.path.basename(event.src_path) == APP:
            self.arm_restart_after_grace_period()

# setup an observer to wath currect directory
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(EventHandler(), '.')
observer.start()
try:
    # observer runs on a separate thread, nothing to do on this one
    input()
finally:
    # make sure we stop the obserev before shutting down
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Note that i've posted this answer cause sometimes there IS a need to launch something when some file, somewhere, changers, and this is an example of how to do so. I would definitely go for either proper IDE or or at least notepad++ with nppexec for the OP's purpose, not this.